# Sign In With Google - Microsoft Edge Error: "Class doesn't support Automation"

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, microsoft-edge, google-signin

My sign in with google button works fine on chrome and firefox. However, when trying to use microsoft edge it throws this error when clicking on the "sign in with google" button.

[image]

After clicking on the button the accounts page that normally appears where you select an account appears for half a second and then disappears.

This is my code for initializing the button:

```
gapi.signin2.render('google_sign_in', {
  'width': 220,
  'height': 50,
  'longtitle': true,
  'theme': 'light',
  'onsuccess': signIn
});
```

Have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of this error by putting the above function into $(document).ready()